# .on('click' в .on('click' как реализовать или чем заменить

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

При нажатии на `<div name="show_details_by_order"` открывается `<div id="order_body_` и стает доступно нажать на `<a name="show_extended_details"`, но при нажатии на нее срабатывает закрытие `<div id="order_body_`, а должно открывать `<div class="order-info"`

Как можно такое реализовать?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('[show_type="details"][order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>"]').addClass('hidden');
 $('[show_type="extended_details"][order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>"]').css({'margin': '-223px 0px 0px'});
 $('#order_body_<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>[show_type="details"][order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>"]').css({'margin': '-<?php echo ($order['count'] * 110) + 170; ?>px 0px 0px'});

 function show_details(){
  $('[show_type="list"][order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>"][name="show_details_by_order"]').on('click',function(){
   if($('[show_type="details"][order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>"]').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $('[show_type="details"][order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>"]').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#order_body_<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>[show_type="details"][order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>"]').css({'margin': '0px'});
   } else {
    $('[show_type="details"][order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>"]').addClass('hidden');
    $('[show_type="details"][order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>"][name="payment_details_block"]').css({'margin': '-181px 0px 0px'});
    $('#order_body_<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>[show_type="details"][order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>"]').css({'margin': '-<?php echo ($order['count'] * 110) + 170; ?>px 0px 0px'});
    $('[show_type="extended_details"][order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>"]').css({'margin': '-223px 0px 0px'});
   }
  });
 }
 
 function show_extended(){
  $('#show_extended_details_<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>[order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>"]').on('click',function(){
   if($('.order-info[show_type="extended_details"][order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>"]').attr('style') == 'margin: 0px;') {
    $('[show_type="extended_details"][order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>"]').css({'margin': '-223px 0px 0px'});
   } else {
    $('[show_type="extended_details"][order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>"]').css({'margin': '0px'});
    
   }
  });
 }

 show_details();
 show_extended();
});
```

```html
<div class="flex profile-order-details clearfix">
 <div class="flex profile-order-heading-list" name="show_details_by_order" order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>" effect_type="style" show_type="list">
  <div class="profile-order-code-wrap">
   <a show_type="list" effect_type="style" order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>" class="novisited sprite-side profile-order-code-link">
    <span class="xhr">№ <?php echo $order['order_id']; ?></span>
   </a>
  </div>
  <div class="profile-order-wrap">
   <time class="profile-order-date"><?php echo $order['date_added']; ?></time>
   <div class="profile-order-count-goods" show_type="list" order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>"><?php echo $order['products']; ?> товар на <nobr><?php echo $order['total']; ?></nobr></div>
   
   <div class="profile-order-list-img" show_type="list" order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>">
    <?php foreach ($order['product_info'] as $product_info) { ?>
    <a class="responsive-img profile-order-g-i-img-link" href="#">
     <img src="<?php echo $product_info['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product_info['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product_info['name']; ?>" style="border:none" width="40" height="26">
    </a>
    <?php } ?>
   </div>
   <div show_type="details" order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>" class="hidden">
    <a name="show_extended_details" order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>" id="show_extended_details_<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>" class="novisited sprite-side profile-order-info-link">
     <span order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>" class="xhr">
      <?php echo $order['info']; ?>
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div style="margin: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="order-info" show_type="extended_details" order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>" style="margin: -223px 0px 0px;">
   <table class="profile-order-info-t">
    <tbody>
     .......
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div style="margin: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
  <div id="order_body_<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>" class="profile-order-goods clearfix" show_type="details" order_id="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>" style="margin: -<?php echo ($order['count'] * 110) + 170; ?>px 0px 0px;">
   ......
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: По моему у вас в обработчиках просто не хватает event.stopPropagation(); Но event туда ещё надо передавать.

Comment: Как правильно его передать, а то я просто его добавляю и он не срабатывает... Могли бы Вы мне помочь с этим? Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Документация говорит что достаточно .click(function( event ) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation(); }

Comment: сработало, не в ту function вписывал... большое спасибо